# Which gam.check() output is most reliable in mgcv R package?

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I have been studying Simon Wood's excellent book to aid my understanding and analysis of GAMs to my data, in addition to looking at some application papers of mgcv.

The gam.check() function outputs both visual and numerical data. In gam.check(), EDF < k. I am using k = 20 and doubling the value as needed.

Here is my output

```
Method: GCV   Optimizer: magic
Smoothing parameter selection converged after 6 iterations.
The RMS GCV score gradient at convergence was 2.061187e-07 .
The Hessian was positive definite.
Model rank =  20 / 20 

Basis dimension (k) checking results. Low p-value (k-index<1) may
indicate that k is too low, especially if edf is close to k'.

        k'    edf    k-index p-value
   s(N) 19.0 18.3     0.4       0
```

above EDF < k, but there is a low p-value (k-index < 1).

The visual plots appear to be problematic[image].

There appears to be heterscedasticity in the residuals and the histogram is right-skewed.

Together, these indicate that k should be doubled until k-index > 1.

My question is: which output is more reliable: visual or numeric?

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: If you find these plots problematic, you have been blessed with some truly well-behaved data and models. For the kind of data I usually have I would suspect overfitting if I saw these diagnostic plots.

Comment: @Roland Then would you say that k = 20 is sufficient to go ahead with model prediction?

Comment: Well, test that with your validation dataset. As I set, I would suspect overfitting.

Comment: The value of the `k-index` and the fact that the `k'` is very close to the effective degrees of freedom of the term all suggest that the dimension of the basis expansion of `N` is too small. I'd double `k` and refit. You don't really provide enough info about the model you fitted to say more.

Comment: @GavinSimpson In my simulation that I have developed I want to fit multiple GAMs. In his book, Simon Wood mentions that one han silly employ a fixed k. Increasing k has minimal effect on computation time in my case. So I would think increasing k to the maximum allowable possible (without R throwing an error) is acceptable. And, essentially, R^2 in the model summary (not shown) is 1...

Comment: The histogram doesn't look right skew to me. What aspect of it are you looking at

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks! You just pointed me to my fault. For some reason, I had assumed that the -0.02 was 0.00... In that case, there would have been skewness.